# How to use local storage on a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

lately on my website I observed that sometimes my code is lost when a router restarts or breaks. I would like to use local storage to store my values of my textarea. My code mostly consists of javascript, and all details are done in html. I would like not to interfere with the javascript I have now. If anyone knows please submit your javascript and for a textarea.

ta,
jake

My textarea code is below;

```html
<div class = "fixed">
<center>
<table>
 <tr><td>Type here</td></tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Save As:</td>
  <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
  <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()"><img src="fl.gif" Save</button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Select file Load:</td>
  <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
  <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load File</button><td>
 </tr>
</table>
</center>
<hr>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = '<html> <body> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ceedweb.css" /> <!--ceedweb, always changing-->';
    textToWrite += document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    textToWrite += '</body> </html>';
 var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/html'});
 var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

 var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
 downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
 downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
 if (window.webkitURL != null)
 {
  
  downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
 }
 else
 {
  
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 }

 downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
 document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
 var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
 {
  var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
  document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
 };
 fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: this might help: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage as `localstorage.setItem('some_key','some_value')` and then retrieve the same as `localstorage.getItem('some_key')`.

But be careful with localstorage as the data stored tends to get stale.

Instead, if you like to persist the data as long as the browser session is active, i.e. till someone closes the browser and re-opens it, you should consider using `sessionStorage` which has the same syntax as localStorage.

Comment: you can write a function onblur of your textArea to save it's contents to the localStorage. And while loading the page, check if the localStorage has some value, then populate your textArea with that value.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob and am confused can you give me this in a more polished manner?*sorry*